# Ubuntu 18.04 Red Dots over screen - Freeze/Crash of OS

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, freeze, 18.10

recently i moved from Windows 10 to Ubuntu, but i have constant problem of my laptop crashing/freezing with red dots and artifacts over screen. After that i need to manually turn off laptop, and start it again. It happens 1 or 2 times a day. You can see it clearly on photos i added. Sometimes it also happens when i just start Ubuntu, go for coffee, get back and its crashed.

I have this issue on all releases, i tried 18.04LTS, 18.10 and Daily Build 19.04, it also happens on Fedora and Mate.

My laptop is ThinkPad Yoga S1 (20CD000MMH), with:
CPU: Intel i5-4200U (4) @ 1.500GHz
GPU: Intel Haswell-ULT
Memory: 7889MiB

I was trying to find something useful, but i only find similar problems on dedicated GPUs which i don't have.

Thank for any help :).

ps: blur on the pictures is added by me for privacy.

[image: Picture of crash Ubuntu]
[image: Picture of crash Feodra]
[image: Picture of crash Ubuntu 2]
[image: Picture of tempatures]

Comment: could be the intel HD graphics. how does adding `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers` then opening up "Software & Sources" app and going to the adition drivers tab help? is there a driver to install if so do so. It's likely you'll also have to add something to your grub. A property to set at bootime this way your system behaves better, but we'll look at that later. Pretty sure it's a driver sort of issue. let's get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I added the repo but no additional drivers are shown here. You can see setup on screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/4BWbgpA

Comment: well that's a bummer. It looks like your hardware is too new or funky to have linux driver support, let's have a look at that grub variable anyhow. type `cat /etc/default/grub | grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` if your return is : `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` go eahead and use `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` to edit that line to  : `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"` and then run `sudo update-grub` then reboot and see if it's better. if not fixed try : `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=pci"` or add both.

Comment: Also I wonder if loging in to an xorg session instead might be of help  : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FtxL.jpg does the glitching happen durring the boot sequence or only once n desktop? it would help to log out to test this.

Comment: Ok, so i edited grub, so i am gonna try it today if its gonna help (it might take a whole day to occur again). If it does not help, im gonna try the reboot=pci and xorg session. Also the freeze/crash never happend in login screen. Also it happend in Wayland on fedora. Also my laptop is 6 years old, i dont think the hw is too new, and i have pretty classic Intel i5-4200U with intagrated grapics, so its odd it does not have good drivers. Thanks for help, i am gonna write once it crashed again or after few days if not.

Comment: while you're testing this, you are running ubuntu 18.10 right? I'd find this more conclusive for this test than 18.04.

Comment: I maked clean install of 18.10 and use the grub change for test right after my comment, so yes :)

Comment: So, it happend again, so i changed it to: "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset reboot=pci". I am gonna write once it happens again or this fixed it.

Comment: So, it happens 3 times in like 10 minutes. Two time right after start. I just give up, i dont know what to do now. So i need to fix this another way. I am gonna distro-hop until i find some that is working.

Comment: ok good luck. try Manjaro and fedora. it's possible either have better driver implementation than ubuntu. really sorry to not have been of better help. hopefully someone with knowledge of this comes by and sees this.

Comment: Thanks for helping me in your free time, really appreciate it. Sometimes there is just not simple solution for this things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after some time, i think i found solution.

Manjaro, Fedora or other distributions did not work, same problem, so i tried Windows (Just for the sake of fixing it) and no, same problem. So i tough its HW problem, i tester RAM (OK) and CPU (also OK), after that i swaped SSD, Wifi/BT card. Still same problem. And after some investigation with BSOD report (i ques that's one thing nice on Windows) i found its USB kernel problem.

And you are not gonna believe it, i unplugged my Wireless mouse dongle, from right port, and now i am using wired on left port, and voila, its 7 days and its working without problem. So its gonna by the wireless mouse dongle or right USB. Its just so bizarre that one small thing could make so much treble. Also back on Ubuntu. Thanks guys for help.